# Paste into text field TideSDK

Tags: javascript, clipboard, tidesdk

I have the following code, I want a user to be able to copy or paste into a text field,
basically imitating a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

My problems are:

1. how to make sure the context menu only appears in text fields
2. how to paste the text into the region.

I have been through the docs and so far I have this NOT working:

```
 var menu = Ti.UI.createMenu();


    menu.addItem('Copy', function() {
        var data =$.("#this").val()

       Ti.UI.Clipboard.getData('text/plain',data);

    });
    menu.addItem('Paste', function() {

       var data =Ti.UI.Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
       $.("#this").val(data)
    });

function showrightmenu(){  Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow().setContextMenu(menu);}
```

I could call this using `oncontextmenu= "showrightmenu()"` but now, how to paste something in this line:

```
    $.(#this).val(Ti.UI.Clipboard.setData('text/plain'))
```

*AM GROPING IN THE DARK.* I'm a newbie to TideSDK, this is my first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question 1

I'm new to TideSDK as well and might be wrong, but as far as I can tell from the API documentation, context menus are bound to a window, and displaying different context menus when right clicking different parts of the window would require you to each time change the window's context menu...

Example:

```js
//Create different menus
var context_menu = Ti.UI.createMenu();
var copy_menu    = Ti.UI.createMenu();
//Add menu items etc.
...

//Change context menus on click events depending on clicked element
$('#some-element').mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.which==3){//detect right click
        editor_window.setContextMenu(context_menu);
    }
});
$('#text-field').mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.which==3){//detext right click
        editor_window.setContextMenu(copy_menu);
    }
});
```

This way, when you click the element with id `some-element`, the first context menu is shown, and when you click the `#text-field` element, the second context menu is shown.

Note that this won't work if one element is inside the other, because then both events are fired.

### Question 2

In this code you supplied:

```js
$.(#this).val(Ti.UI.Clipboard.setData('text/plain'))
```

You want to use `Ti.UI.Clipboard.getData` and not `Ti.UI.Clipboard.setData`, since you want to get the text stored in the clipboard and then put it into the text field. Also, you might want to change `$.(#this)` to `$("#this")` or `$(this)`.

This should work:

```js
$("#some-element").val(Ti.UI.Clipboard.getData('text/plain'))
```

### Remark

You seem to be confused about how to use jQuery. To select an element, you use `$()` and not `$.()`. Also, with `$("#example")` you select the DOM element with the id `example`. `$(this)` is used inside a function called when an event is fired, and refers to the element on which the event was fired. `$("#this")` is not the same as `$(this)`. Hope that helps a bit...